# Simple modules and trivial source modules

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $(K,\mathcal{O},k)$ be a large enough $p$-modular system.

In this context, I would like to ask what is known about the following question:

> when are simple $kG$-modules trivial source modules?

So far, I have found the following three pieces of information.

1. There is a result by Okuyama stating that if $M$ is a simple trivial source module
   then also its Green correspondent is simple.
2. We know from Fong-Swan that the decomposition matrices of soluble groups have an identity submatrix of maximal
   possible size. Does this give us some further information? All simples are then liftable,
   but are those lifts already trivial source lattices?
3. In the context of Alperin's weight conjecture: a simple module is a weight module if and only if it is a trivial source module.

Are there more details / references / results known?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Lifts of simple modules in the $p$-solvable case are not always trivial source. You might try reading about endopermutation modules and endotrivial modules